# jquery ui autocomplete inside jQuery Ui Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi I have a JQuery Ui (jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js) inside a Dialog. When I start typing on the box I get the dropdown of items but it hides right away? Does anyone know why? Here is my code:

```
 $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemId = $(this).attr("data-item-id");
        var ajaxurl = $(this).attr('data-ajax-refresh-url');
        var dialogId = $(this).attr("data-dialog-id");
        $('<div><img src="Content/images/spinner.gif" /> Loading...</div>')
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        width: 'auto',
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        buttons: {
                            "Save": function () {
                                $(this).find('form').submit();
                            },
                            close: function () {
                                if (typeof itemId != "undefined") {
                                    $.get(ajaxurl, { id: itemId },
                                        function (data) {
                                            // The data returned is a table <tr>
                                            $("#Row" + itemId).replaceWith(data);
                                        });
                                    bindConfirm();
                                }
                                $(this).remove();
                            }

                        },
                        modal: true
                    }).load(this.href, function () {
                        $(this).find("input[data-autocomplete]").autocomplete({ source: $(this).find("input[data-autocomplete]").attr("data-autocomplete") });
                    });

    });
```

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in this verison. I downlaod the jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min version and the problem is fixed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They also had problems in early 1.8 releases. I remember applying a custom CSS selector to increase zIndex manually.

See also: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-inside-a-dialog-1-8rc2

Comment: The Z-Index issue is solved in the final version of 1.8.14. But thanks for the comment.